# Custom service start is not working in OLE6. Where am i going wrong?

Tags: linux, rhel

I have Created a service in /etc/init.d. It calls another script file catalina.sh within it.
It starts fine with

> ./Service_name start

but when i try

> service Service_name start

the script is executed but the service does not start
Here is the concerned part of the script file

> 

```
start(){
    echo -n "Starting $VAR"
    PID="$(pgrep -f $VAR)"
    if [ "$PID" = "" ]
            then
            cd /home/com/Analytics/servers/$VAR/bin
            ./catalina.sh start >/dev/null
                    while [ $temp -lt $startime ]
                    do
                    sleep 5
                    echo -n " ."
                    temp=$(( $temp + 5 ))
                    done
            echo -e "\e[0;32m               [ OK ]  \e[0m"
            else
            echo -e "\e[0;31m                       [ FAILED ]  \e[0m"
            echo -e "\e[0;33m $VAR is already running.  \e[0m"
    fi
```

}

Also i would like to mention that

> service Service_name stop

and

> service Service_name status

works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was requirement of bash of JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME when catalina.sh is called as a service.. Which was fixed by exporting JAVA_HOME.

> export JAVA_HOME=path_to_jdk